# Grey cursor in CLion deletes code, and I don't know how to get rid of it

Tags: c, clion

When I edit code in the middle of statements, it replaces the current code around it. I cannot find a way to replace this with a normal cursor that only inserts data instead of replacing it. Is that functionality possible in CLion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have the editor in replace mode.
You can switch from replace to insert mode pressing the insert (`INS`) button.